# Is it possible to chain WorkManager periodic workers?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I just started looking into WorkManager and I can't find any solution for chaining periodic workers. I'm my app it's necessary having workers to run in parallel because they have same constraints.
Maybe I should create a single periodic worker that will enqueue a chain of workers needed?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are having same constraint, you may also don't need to have different worker's.
Create a single periodic worker and perform your action in dowork method.
Chaining of worker is suitable and helpful if result of one is dependant on other.

Comment: Results are not dependant, but the sequence is.

Comment: Even that can be done with single worker like this.
doWork(){
performTaskA();
performTaskb();
performTaskC();
}